# how to compare rows having same id and display minimum based on some other attribute

Tags: sql

I have this following table

```
TA-ID     quantity
10139       1
10139       3
10139       4
10140       5
10140       1
10141       6
10141       4
10141       3
```

my desired output is following

```
TA-ID     quantity
10139       1
10140       1
10141       3
```

please help to construct query for this and explain

Comment: Seems like a simple task. What have you tried? Giving you a hint : Use `MIN()` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Check out GROUP BY, combined with aggregate function MIN().

Answer (score 0):

Use group by to get unique ID's and MIN() to get the lowest value for that column

```
 SELECT TA-ID, MIN(quantity) 
 FROM 'table' 
 GROUP BY TA-ID
```

Comment: Giving straight solution for such basic task will not do anything good in his career. OP should learn it by himself.

Comment: It's always nice to have someone help you when you don't know where to look on the web.

Comment: @DieVeenman: I believe, it is nice to show the way, give some hints to look after. So, OP can learn something.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TA-ID, MIN(quantity)Quantity FROM Tbl1 GROUP BY TA-ID
```